# "Would you like to automatically move these comments to chat?" could be clearer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, wording, move-to-chat

When two users message each other in the comments one too many times, Stack Exchange presents a message as follows:

> Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

I clicked on it thinking it would *move* the discussion to chat. Well, it kind of did that. It *copied* the discussion to chat, and left the original comments behind.

There's an easy fix for this: use the correct verb. [Another user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/267099/davidpostill) suggested...

> Would you like to **continue** this discussion in chat?

... and my original suggestion was...

> Would you like to automatically **copy** this discussion to chat?

What do you think?

Comment: I think **continue** this discussion **in** chat is even better.

Comment: @DavidPostill I like your idea a little bit better than mine, so I absorbed it into the question and gave you credit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that existing comments are not moved.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Automatically move this discussion to chat]

If you have to click on a link, what is **automatic** about it?

See [definition of automatic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/automatic).

> ...  occurring independently of volition ...

If it was automatic, we wouldn't need to be asked the question.

---

This is **manually** moving the discussion to chat, right?

I suggest a wording change: "Would you like to move this discussion to chat?".

And that is assuming the discussion is **moved**. If not, it should be: "Would you like to copy these comments to a chat room?"

---

Also, after doing that today ("moving" the discussion to chat) the message still appears:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/374579/79426

[image: Continue in chat]

- First, the discussion was copied, not moved.
- Second, it is still offering to move it to chat (even though the link to chat is already there). Does it want it "moved" a second time?
- Third, because the other messages are still there, the message saying "Let us continue this discussion in chat" is hidden until you expand the messages.

Comment: The option is not always displayed.  There should be a way for a user with significant reputation, to invite a user with less then the required reputation to normally chat, into a chatroom in order to avoid extended discussions.  When you are trying to literally pull information, in order to get enough information to answer the question, it's difficult to submit a reasonable amount of comments.

Comment: I think "automatic" means that you don't have to create the chat room or copy the comments. The system automatically does that for you if you click on the link.

Comment: Isn't that implied that you don't have to create the chat room yourself? I mean, otherwise it would respond: "oh, that's nice, well go ahead and do it yourself then.". I think a link that asks you if you want to do something implies that if you click the link that thing will be done. Therefore it isn't automatic because you had to click the link. If it was automatic the system would move lengthy sets of comments **by itself** without user intervention.